# Does the javascript/NodeJS compiler automatically make these small efficiency tweaks, or should be careful to implement them myself? (Example given)

Tags: javascript, json, performance

I am making a program that accesses pretty large API's and it made me curious about something that might help its overall efficiency

Lets say I have a JSON resource that is located at `data.Orders[i].TgtResource` , where `data` is Parsed JSON that has a resource called `Orders` which is an array of other resources and `TgtResource` is the resource I am after.

Would something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.Orders.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < data.Orders[i].length; j++){
         (extract resource)
    }
}
```

Become interpreted by a compiler as something slightly more efficient, like this:

```
    var totalSize = data.Orders.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < totalSize; i++){
        var innerArraySize = data.Orders[i].length;
        for(var j = 0; j < innerArraySize; j++){
             (extract resource)
        }
    }
```

Or is it up to me to make that small adjustment? I worked a bit with C and C++ and I saw, after viewing some of the assembly code my programs generated, that this kind of stuff was automatically done by the compiler I was using, so I would like to know if this kind of stuff happens with JS.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hmm. Javascript is not compiled. It is interpreted.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that it does not do what I posted above?

Comment: Scratch that. Just did my research. I guess these little code changes will make a big difference!

Comment: On a side note. Arrays in javascript have a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method. Using that makes caching the length unnecessary.

Comment: If I have already written code as above, is it worth going in through my code and changing it to a foreach loop? I'm sorry if these questions are dumb, I am attempting to squeeze out any source of inefficiency.

Comment: There is a jsperf test that will answer that for you. [for vs forEach](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37)

Comment: Holy god.... that site is amazing!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Actually, the results of the benchmarks confused the hell out of me. forEach ended up being the slowest, and the fastest was a forloop going in reverse?

Comment: It appears that it is. Remember that it is dependent on environment and load. The way you implemented it came in such a close second and IMO is more intuitive that I would stick with it.